# How to define variable and constant in flutter?

Tags: android, android-studio, flutter, dart

as we define in swift

constant with `let`

variable with `var`

how to define in flutter?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Variables:

```
var number = 42;
```

Constants:

> If you never intend to change a variable, use final or const, either
>   instead of var or in addition to a type. A final variable can be set
>   only once; a const variable is a compile-time constant. (Const
>   variables are implicitly final.) A final top-level or class variable
>   is initialized the first time it’s used.

```
final name = 'Bob'; // Without a type annotation
final String nickname = 'Bobby';
```

> Use const for variables that you want to be compile-time constants. If
>   the const variable is at the class level, mark it static const. Where
>   you declare the variable, set the value to a compile-time constant
>   such as a number or string literal, a const variable, or the result of
>   an arithmetic operation on constant numbers:

```
const bar = 1000000; // Unit of pressure (dynes/cm2)
const double atm = 1.01325 * bar; // Standard atmosphere
```

More here: https://dart.dev/guides/language/language-tour#variables